# Visual Studio c# allow build with errors for manual handling

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, object

I consume a few different versions of the same third party WCF service implemented at different customers. I face the problem, that I cannot use same code because of differences:
- Old versions sometimes don't hold all methods, or parameters on methods
- There might be a few custom properties for certain customers.

Example:

I can do these two versions:

```
// configured with http://service.customer1111.com/Service1111.svc?wsdl
using(var s = new project.Service.Service1111Client()){
...
}
```

or

```
// configured with http://service.customer2222.com/Service2222.svc?wsdl
using(var s = new project.Service.Service2222Client()){
...
}



Member m = s.MemberGet(1, 1); // same for both 
var name = m.Name; //same for both
var age = m.AgeOfPet; // only valid on customer1111 - dosen't exist on 2222
var bmi = s.ComputeBMI(m); // method on 1111
var bmi2 = s.ComputeBMI(m, 2); // method on 2222
```

Right now I have to find 10 different places in 10.000 lines of code and comment out wrong verions to be able to build the project when changing service.

I would like to:

```
Decimal bmi;
if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["customerID"] == "1111")    
    {
       // method on 1111 - ignore build error on others
       bmi = s.ComputeBMI(m); 
    }
    else
    {
       // method on others - ignore build error on 1111
       bmi2 = s.ComputeBMI(m, 2); 
    }
```

But that obviously will not build.

I am looking for a way to "ignore build errors" in certain blocks of code.

The differences are of minimal effect to my code otherwise, and creating and parsing to an abstract class is a huge task.

Any way to achieve that?

Comment: well you can use the #if #else #endif compiler directives, but that still requires you to edit all the code..

Comment: This might actually work! Or it seems like it does anyway :-) I will still need to recompile for different services, but the task of comment in/out 10-20 different places can now be just editing of one conditional symbol on the project properties... Great!

Comment: go ahead and write an answer if you want to get credited :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use c# preprocessor directives (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) like so

```
 Decimal bmi;
    #if
       bmi = s.ComputeBMI(m); 
    #else
       bmi = s2.ComputeBMI(m, 2);
    #endif
```